# HTTP Request without cookies

Tags: http, cookies, browser

I have an web application in which I generate a download link to an external google resource. This request usually needs a cookie. Because of the cross domain policy I currently download the files with curl and then pass them through to the user. Now those files are large. So I was looking for a way to download them directly through the clients browser.

Playing around I've found out that I can append the cookie in question to the http query, but this only works if no other cookies are set! Since it's google almost all users will have set some cookies for .google.com. Is there any way (maybe some security feature or bug) I can trigger a download request for that file in the users browser without sending any cookies along.

Answer (score 1):

I discovered that I can make a request to `*.google.com.` (notice the **.** at the end) and then most browsers won't send any cookies set for `.google.com` . I've did a quick test using browsershots and on my own devices. The hack works in almost all browsers except for Safari (desktop and mobile) and some no name browsers.

While this works, I've decided not to use that method because the file name will be set to something unusable (no file extension).